# Gnome Emoji Picker and Characters app do not show Noto Color Emoji emojis

Tags: gnome, fonts, emoji

In Ubuntu 20.04, using either Characters app or Emoji Picker, the emojis in Noto Color Emoji are not available.

One example is typing 'butter', only the butterfly appears in search instead of also having the food, butter.

In Characters, if I filter on Noto Color Emoji font, nothing appears.

What might the issue be?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Emote
`sudo snap install emote`
https://github.com/tom-james-watson/Emote

I assigned a custom shortcut to it and completely replaced that rubbish emoji picker